# Angular 9: file replacements doesn't work

Tags: angular

Angular `fileReplacements` doesn't replace files if they occur in `assets`.
This code doesn't work in Angular 9 but works in version 8:

```
"assets": [
  "src/web.config"
]
...
"fileReplacements": [
  {
    "replace": "src/web.config",
    "with": "src/configs/web.stage.config"
  }
]
```

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should copy assets using the assets property instead of file replacements.

This is a simplification of my `angular.json` file, showing only the relevant properties under `configurations`.

```
{  
  "projects": {
    "my-project": {      
      "architect": {
        "build": {          
          "configurations": {
            "staging": {
              "assets": [
                { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
                { "glob": "web.config", "input": "src/environments/staging/", "output": "/" }
              ],              
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "assets": [
                { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
                { "glob": "web.config", "input": "src/environments/prod/", "output": "/" }
              ],            
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. this works... but only when build, not when serve :-(

Comment: also see here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16779#issuecomment-579183693

Comment: found an amazing article https://medium.com/@pedrorolo/angular-setting-angular-json-b485dedc29d7

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on angular 9 and downgrading **"@angular-devkit/build-angular"** from version **^0.1000.3** to **^0.900.7** did the trick